Shared state between server and client components in Blazor
My goal is to have two components with different render modes sharing state.
<CounterPresenter /> (InteractiveServer)
<Counter /> (InteractiveWebAssembly)
Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:
Program.cs
using BlazorApp1.Client.Services;
using BlazorApp1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CounterStateService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp1.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Program.cs (Client)
using BlazorApp1.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
    new HttpClient { }
);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterStateService>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();

CounterStateService.cs
namespace BlazorApp1.Client.Services
{
    public class CounterStateService
    {
        public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
    }
}

CounterStateController.cs
using BlazorApp1.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorApp1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CounterStateController(CounterStateService counterStateService) : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet(nameof(GetCounterState))]
        public IActionResult GetCounterState()
        {
            return Ok(counterStateService.CurrentCount);
        }

        [HttpGet(nameof(IncrementCounterState))]
        public IActionResult IncrementCounterState()
        {
            counterStateService.CurrentCount = counterStateService.CurrentCount + 1;

            return Ok(counterStateService.CurrentCount);
        }
    }
}

CounterPresenter.razor
@using BlazorApp1.Client.Services

@rendermode InteractiveServer

@inject CounterStateService CounterStateService

<span>Current count: @(CounterStateService is null ? "Loading" : CounterStateService.CurrentCount)</span>

Counter.razor
@page "/counter"

@rendermode InteractiveAuto

@inject HttpClient HttpClient

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @(CurrentCount is null ? "Loading..." : CurrentCount)</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCountAsync">Click me</button>

@code {
    public int? CurrentCount { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CurrentCount = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("https://localhost:7095/CounterState/GetCounterState");
    }

    private async Task IncrementCountAsync()
    {
        CurrentCount = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("https://localhost:7095/CounterState/IncrementCounterState");
    }
}

The issue I have is that CounterStateService.CurrentCount is always 0 when IncrementCounterState is incrementing the count. It seems CounterStateController receives a new instance of CounterStateService each time the endpoint IncrementCounterState is hit. I am obviously doing something wrong.
However, is what I am trying to achieve possible?

You defined CounterStateController in Server project but you didn't  define mapping rule...

I assume you're looking for real time updates of the presenter when you update the counter in Server/WASM/Auto render modes.
Everything is possible, but you need to use an external state management system or build your own.
You have, and are interacting with, two instances of CounterStateService.  One is on the server in the running application code, and one is in the WASM instance running in the browser.  They are running in two totally different contexts.

So having a Blazor application where components share state and have different rendering modes is not supported "out-of-the-box"? Do we have to choose one or the other? What's the point of InteractiveAuto if shared state is not supported?

"Do we have to choose one or the other?".  Yes.  Using InteractiveAuto is the total opposite of the best of both worlds: building an application using InteractiveAuto is sooo complicated.  See https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html and https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering for a personal view on why.

Thanks for your input and the articles, we will have to consider what to do here.

Firstly, I modifty your codes in Program.cs of Server project like below. Using AddSingleton instead of your AddScoped. Because you are exposing the API which is stateless, so that using AddScoped will cause a result that the response is always 1.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterStateService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
...
app.MapControllers();



This would cause multiple users (browser sessions) to share state. The state of the counter should be scoped to a single user but be able to be shared between the server and the client.

I get your point. But anyway, using scoped couldn't help you share the state between your client and server, I'm afraid we can't work on this way and need to find another approach. Maybe an external system/database which can be used to store the state?
